# integrated terminal icon issue

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

I am sitting on a mac os device running Catalina and using iterm2 as my default terminal.
In VS Code, in my settings.json, I have the following setup for my envirement:

```
{
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Hyper Term Theme",
  "terminal.external.osxExec": "iTerm.app",
  "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/zsh",
  "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "'Menlo for Powerline', 'PowerlineSymbols', 'Awesome Regular'",
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "window.zoomLevel": 2,
}
```

I have checked that I have the fonts in my settings installed on my machine.
This is the screendump from my integrated terminal:

[image]

And this is the screendumpt from my default iterm2 terminal:

[image]

So, the icons from iterm2 are not visible in my integrated terminal in VS Code, what am I missing in my settings.json file in VS Code, and also the righthand side output of?

> took 1d 2h 18mon 26s

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your font is cached and stored in an accessible directory.
2. In your settings.json add:
   `"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Your font",`
   OR:
   Ctrl+, > search for "terminal.integrated.font" > Enter "Your font"

I have this on Linux Debian 10:

1. MesloLGS NF Regular.ttf file in ~/.local/share/fonts. Then cache the font:
   `fc-cache -vf ~/.local/share/fonts`
2. In my settings.json:
   `"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "MesloLGS NF",`

[image]

Comment: I have this already in my settings.json:
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "'Menlo for Powerline', 'PowerlineSymbols', 'Awesome Regular'",

Comment: Try with different font names that look like yours @user2371684  
I have this file font file: MesloLGS NF Regular.ttf  
- "MesloLGS NF Regular" Font Family didn't work.  
- "MesloLGS NF" Font Family finally worked.